# spring cloud stream - can a spring cloud stream appliction exit explicitly?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am not sure if my understand is correct. We launch a spring cloud stream appliction and subscribe to a topic. The application will be running and mornitoring the topic for new message, except we send kill signal to quit. I was thinking if we could quit spring cloud application explicityly, like waiting 5 minutes and no new messages come in? Or processed 1000 records and quit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stop the application for this as it will bring the entire JVM (which you can always do if you want). 
Typically for use cases like this you `stop/pause/start/resume` bindings individually essentially allowing other bindings to function.
[Here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_visualization_and_control) is where you can find more information

Comment: You can detect an idle consumer as discussed [here for Kafka](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#pause-resume). A similar capability is available for the RabbitMQ binder too using a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` to set the container's `idleEventInterval`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg and @Gary. Both methods are valid to stop consumer. The situation I want to deal with is we are going to package the messages and send to 3rd partner, with control header - like hash of records content, sequence number and columns' header. So the point is that we need a cut-point(last message received?) to generate the file. The first thought that we could exhaust all the messages of one batch, which we send to input daily, generate the file and send, then stop for next new run. Quit JVM will give the signal to context(like k8s job), and we know we can move forward for next step.