# how to pause consumers from consuming messages in spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I ran into situation where I want to pause consumers to stop consuming messages through spring boot application and messages should not be lost from queue, I am using amqp and spring cloud stream.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream.adoc#binding_visualization_control this states only kafka has this option.

Can I do something to fix this for rabbit-mq binder?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058207/spring-cloud-stream-can-a-spring-cloud-stream-appliction-exit-explicitly

Comment: That I have already mentioned it's available for Kafka only.

Answer (score 0):

Pause is required for Kafka because if you `stop()` the container, the broker will rebalance and give the partitions to another instance. With RabbitMQ, the queue remains when the container is `stop()`ped so the issue doesn't arise there (as long as you specify a `group`).

You can't `stop()` the container for an anonymous consumer (no `group`) because such consumers use an auto-delete queue. There is no way to pause such consumers (the AMQP protocol has no such mechanism).

Comment: A dependent service on the consumer service required downtime and for obvious reason I wanted to hold information for sometime.
 I thought if we can do this thing in case of dlq, why not for normal queue.

Comment: You can, as long as the consumer is in a group.

Comment: I do have consumer in group i.e

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.xyz.destination=xyz
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.xyz.group=xyz_group

can you guide me how?

Comment: Then, when the consumer is stopped, the messages will continue to be scored in the queue.

Comment: How can I pause the consumer selectively, while running the application.(Even I am okay to stop the specific consumer through config but not code)

Comment: Look at the code in `BindingsEndpoint`, it searches the input bindings for the consumer and stops/starts it.